# Can't select Person Account -> Identifier (Health Cloud) as a dynamic related list

Tags: administration, related-list, lightning-app-builder

I am trying to display a standard object (Identifier) using the dynamic related list - single on Person Account. However, Identifier doesn't show up in the list of related objects. Dynamic related lists work for standard and custom objects so I don't see why it's not working. The only thing I can think of is that it's because the Identifier object is a standard object for Health Cloud and is simply not supported. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not there, it means it's not supported. This is noted in the documentation for [Standard Lightning Page Components](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_page_components.htm&type=5#:%7E:text=Builder%20properties%20pane.-,Dynamic%20Related%20List%20%E2%80%93%20Single%20Component,-NOTE%20The%20Dynamic) that not all standard objects support it.

> NOTE The Dynamic Related List – Single component is available for a select and growing set of Salesforce standard objects and for custom objects, but not for external objects. **If you don’t see Dynamic Related List – Single in the list of standard components, it’s not currently available for the object associated with the record page**. To suggest prioritized object support for the Dynamic Related List – Single component, go to IdeaExchange.

You'll see some ideas have already been created for other unsupported Standard objects:

- [Field Service Objects](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000KVEupUAH/dynamic-related-list-missing-field-service-objects)
- [Contracts](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000J5VfFUAV/dynamic-related-list-missing-objects)